# Namespace issue class not found

Tags: php

In my root folder I have a file folder that has my common files I use between different projects.
/files
I have a file redis.php that has Redis class that I want to use in one of my project in /var/www/html/project/example.php
The Class Redis is in /file/library/storage/redis/redis.php

my redis.php has

```
<?php

    namespace file\library\storage\redis;

    class Redis{

        public function init(){
            $redis = new Redis();
            $redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
        }


    }



?>
```

and in my example.php I call that namespace like

```
$redis = new \file\library\storage\redis\Redis();
$redis->init();
```

but it gives me an error

```
[Mon May 27 12:25:48 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'file\\library\\storage\\redis\\Redis' not found
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: and do you have an autoloader for this? I don't think its going to work without a proper autoloader that tells php where to look for your files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is an **autoloader** that can map your namespaces to actual paths and include the class files before you're creating an instance of them. Take a look at the commonly used [PSR-0 autoloader](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md#example-implementation).

```
<?php

function autoload($className)
{
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName  = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';

    require $fileName;
}
spl_autoload_register('autoload');
```

If you include this code in `/var/www/html/project/example.php`, what happens then when you try to make an instance

```
$redis = new \file\library\storage\redis\Redis();
```

Is that it will try to include this file first

```
/var/www/html/project/file/library/storage/redis/Redis.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include the file that contains the class. You can do it manually using: require_once 'redis.php' OR create a rontina autoload as stated in the first answer